# babel-preset-react outputting ansi for error

Tags: babeljs

How can I stop babel-preset-react from outputting garbledy gook like this?

```
[0m [90m 10 | [39m
[90m 11 | [39m[36mexport[39m [36mdefault[39m [36mfunction[39m [33mSVG[39m() {
[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 12 | [39m [36mreturn[39m [33m<[39m[33mdiv[39m id[33m=[39m[32m"svg-container"[39m [33m<[39m[33msvg[39m [36mclass[39m[33m=[39m[32m"circle"[39m xmlns[33m=[39m[32m"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"[39m[33m>[39m
[90m | [39m [31m[1m^[22m[39m
[90m 13 | [39m [33m<[39m[33mcircle[39m
[90m 14 | [39m cx[33m=[39m[32m"50"[39m
[90m 15 | [39m cy[33m=[39m[32m"50"[39m[0m
```

to the browser console with webpack? It shows up fine in the terminal, but the browser console can't support ansi, I don't think